# How do I make a foreach loop display items on more than one column?

Tags: php, joomla, foreach

I'm trying to modify a joomla module and I have a small problem (which is not joomla related, thus no code necessary).

I have a foreach loop which has a block of code in it which displays an article. It repeats itself as many times as you set it up in the admin panel. I want to add the feature that makes this module display items on more than 1 column. All I need is the perk, I think I have everything else covered.

Basically how do I modify a simple foreach loop so that it displays articles on more than one column?

Instead of this

a

b

c

d

e

I want this

a ........ d

b ........ e

c

Comment: Are "columns" part of a table, or determined by adjacent divs, or ___?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the count of results and work from the middle if you're sticking with tables

```
$half_count = floor(count($entries) / 2);
for($i=0;$i<$half_count;$i++)
{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $entries[$i] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . (isset($entries[$half_count + $i]) ? $entries[$half_count + $i]: '') . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a simple way to do it :

```
php > $arr = array(1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
php > for ($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i+=2) { print $arr[$i] . "\t" . $arr[$i+1] . "\n"; }
1       2
3       4
5       6
7       8
9       10
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you won't be able to do it with a foreach statement but with a for.

For example:

```
$iterations = (count($array_of_items) % 2) ? (count($array_of_items) / 2) + 1 : count($array_of_items) / 2;
for ($i = 0; $i <= $iterations; $i++) {
if (isset($array_of_items[$i+3]))
   echo $array_of_items[$i].'........'.$array_of_items[$i+3];
else
   echo $array_of_items[$i];
}
```

Really simple code without so little info but could make the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of outputting in the for loop, I would create two arrays of the articles in the for loop. Then loop through those arrays to create your columns outside of the main loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have little info in the question, but here's something you could use

```
$arr = array("a","b","c","d","e","f");

for ($i = 0; $i<count($arr); $i++){
    echo $arr[$i]."    ". $arr[$i+3] ."\n";
    if($i == 2){ break;} //Modify 2 as more alphabets are added
}
```

Outputs

```
a    d
b    e
c    f
```

Comment: "Modify 2 as more alphabets are added" - or you could do something like "$num_cols = 2; ... if ($i % (count($arr) / $num_cols) == 0) { break; }" - with probably a call to ceil(), floor(), or round(*) thrown in around the division for good measure

Answer (score 0):

For a generic solution, assuming a packed array....

```
function show_table($data, $columns)
{
    $items=count($data);
    $iters=$items/$columns + ($items % $columns) ? 1 : 0;
    for ($y=0; $y<$iters; $y++) {
      for ($x=0; $x<$columns; $x++) {
         $offset=$y*$columns + $x;
         if ($offset<$items) print $data[$offset] . ' ';
      }
      print "\n";
    }
}
```